# post an image file to server

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

[db.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vXQr.png)
The image file I posted to my db.json is missing.

```
const createPost = async (title, image, description) => {
 const data = new FormData();
    data.append('title', title);
    data.append('image', image);
    data.append('description', description);

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/posts', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    const updatedPosts = [...posts, response.data];
    setPosts(updatedPosts);
  };
```

```
export const Form = ({ createPost }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    createPost(title, image, description);
    setImage('');
    setTitle('');
    setDescription('');
  };

  const uploadImage = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setImage(file);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitForm} encType="multipart/form-data">
      <div className="image">
        <label>Import Image</label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={(e) => uploadImage(e)} />
      </div>
      <div className="action">
        <Button className="button">Create</Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I want to post my data to my server. But, only an image file is missing in my db.json. What is the better way I fixed the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your header's content type have to be multipart/form-data or you have to convert your image to base64 string and no need to add it to form data and also if you are using express you may have to use bodyparserand fs packages too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` takes only function name. So, modify this

```
onChange={(e) => uploadImage(e)}
```

to

```
onChange={uploadImage}
```

because you have already defined `uploadImage` function earlier in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I think your problem is in the Backend code. But, try to **Change the order of `data.append`**, move `data.append(file)` to the last.

```
data.append('title', title)
data.append('description', description)
// ...appends some field
data.append('file', file)
```

If not work, please show me your backend code. (how to generate db.json file)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).